# Unity 5 NetworkManager StartHost & StartClient Properties

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

Is there any way to change the `.networkAddress` and `.networkPort` properties within the `NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost()` and `NetworkManager.singleton.StartClient()` objects? I tried `NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost().networkAddress = GetLocalIp()` where `GetLocalIp()` is a function that gets the computers local IP so another person on a different computer can connect.

I'm trying to make it so I don't have to use localHost for my multiplayer game as that is quite pointless to run two instances of the same game on the same machine.

Any ideas on how to do this so that one computer is a host machine and the other is a client that connects to the host and they are able to play on the same map.

Answer (score 0):

For server (and for server part of host), the following worked for me:

```
NetworkManager.singleton.serverBindToIP = true;
NetworkManager.singleton.serverBindAddress = Network.player.ipAddress;
```

networkAddress seems to be used for client only.